# Usage of ruby_parser, AST in prior 1.8.7 and S-expression in ruby?

Tags: ruby, s-expression, parse-tree, ruby-parser

Recently I am converting the ror project that uses ParseTree in ruby 1.8.7 to ruby 1.9.3

Figured out that ParseTree cannot work with 1.9.3, Searched for it in bunch of googlers, still stuck with some code-migration

Found various alternative like ruby_parser, sourcify, parse_tree_reloaded, etc...

All those have their limitation e.g. sourcify cannot do the dynamic analysis parsing, viz. usage of eval.

Going all through these, I wanted to know the best-usage of AST/Parsing/SExp in the ruby community and what might be the alternative in ruby 1.9.3 if I don't choose the AST path?

Some use-cases pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ryan Davis, who I think is the main author of ParseTree, listed some libraries that used ParseTree in this [blog post](http://blog.zenspider.com/blog/2009/04/parsetree-eol.html). Many of these libraries were maintained by Davis himself. If he doesn't know how to upgrade a library that uses ParseTree, I don't know what chance the rest of us have!